# Receive header parameters in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, http-headers, asp.net-core-mvc, jax-rs

I am migrating from a Java Jax-Rs API into ASP.NET. I have custom header params that I pass into the API.

[image]

[image]

I couldn't find the way to do the same in ASP.NET.

This is what I have so far:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public String login()
  {
     return "works";       
  }
```

I searched in every tutorial I found and couldn't find any mention to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET Core does support [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) from the header, so, to get similar to your action listed you could use.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public String login([FromHeader(Name="usuario")] string usuario, [FromHeader(Name="pass")] string pass))
  {
     return "works";       
  }
```

You could then interact with the properties as desired.

Comment: Still surprised about how easy it was to do (and how common) and how hard was to find documentation.

Comment: Once you get used to some of the concepts you can dig into the documentation, but it isn't always as easy as you would hope.  I run into this a lot and it is why I often blog about the "fun" things that I've read in documentation